Missing projection classes in Spring Boot 3 with Querydsl
I'm trying to migrate querydsl based project with Spring Boot 3.
Test project: https://github.com/rcbandit111/querydsl_migration_poc
With Spring Boot 2 the following configuration is working fine:
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jpa'

But with Spring Boot 3 Qxxx classes are not generated under build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java
Any idea how to fix this?

Spring Boot uses JakartaEE not JavaEE. If you haven't changed the dependencies you are still running JavaEE to generate the QueryDSL classes which will not work.
